# returning the average and the std deviation of a table row - MySQL

Tags: mysql

One how of my table `profile_test` looks like this (the column names are show at the front of the value):

```
  1: profile1_test_1 153.3
  2: profile1_test_2 152.7
  3: profile1_test_3 151.5
  4: profile1_test_4 151.4
  5: profile1_test_5 151.7
  6: profile1_test_6 151.8
  7: profile1_test_7 156.7
  8: profile1_test_8 157.0
  9: profile1_test_9 156.8
  10: profile1_test_10 156.7
```

I would like to know how to create a `SQL` query that would return me the `AVG` and the `STD` of each row ( not the entire column )? The database is `MySQL`.What I'm trying to do is average across different columns ( they are the results of different tests run, so it's interesting to know their avg and std ).

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: MySQL has a built-in `AVG()` aggregate function. But are you really trying to average across different columns, not the same column in multiple rows?

Comment: @Barmar Yes ... I'm trying to average across different columns ...

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select rowid, avg(profile_test), stddev(profile_test)
from (select rowid,
             (case when n = 1 then profile1_test_1
                   when n = 2 then profile1_test_2
                   . . .
                   when n = 10 then profile1_test_10 
              end) as profile_test
      from profile_test cross join
           (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all
            select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 10
           ) nums
      ) t
group by rowid
```

There is probably a more efficient way by writing the complicated arithmetic on each row, but this should work well for moderate data sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a UNION to get all the columns into a single column in a subquery:

```
select run, avg(val), stddev(val)
from (select run, profile_test_1 val
      from mytable
      union
      select run, profile_test_2 val
      from mytable
      union
      select run, profile_test_3 val
      from mytable
      union
      ...) x
 group by run
```